# How to return std::array of different size based on compile-time switch?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

I need to create an array of static data, where the size (and data) is known at compile time, but differs between build configurations.

This is a very dumbed-down version of what I'm trying to do
(Please ignore glaring bad practices in this code as it is just an example):

```cpp
constexpr ProductType PRODUCT = ProductType::A;
constexpr size_t dataSize() { return PRODUCT == ProductType::A ? 3 : 4; }

constexpr std::array<int, dataSize()> createArray()
{
    if constexpr (dataSize() == 4) {
        return std::array<int, dataSize()>{1, 2, 3, 4};
    } else {
        return std::array<int, dataSize()>{1, 2, 3};
    }
}
```

But this code fails to compile. The first branch of the `constexpr-if` is still evaluated and deemed invalid:

```
<source>:22:54: error: too many initializers for 'std::array<int, 3>'
   22 |         return std::array<int, dataSize()>{1, 2, 3, 4};
      |                                                      ^
```

But reading the docs I was under the impression that the code in the non-active branch of `constexpr-if` **can** contain code that will return wrong type, so why wouldn't this work?

Comment: `if constexpr` only works the way you're trying if it's in a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you pass to `if constexpr` does not depend on any template parameters, so both branches are compiled.

[From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

> Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. `if constexpr` is not a substitute for the `#if` preprocessing directive
>
> ```cpp
> void f()
> {
>     if constexpr(false)
>     {
>         int i = 0;
>         int *p = i; // Error even though in discarded statement
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Enlico. But is what I'm trying to do even possible using templates?

Comment: @AviShukron: You can just use a `template <size_t N = dataSize()>` and then change every `dataSize()` inside your `createArray` to just `N`. Because N is a template parameter, the constexpr now works.

Comment: @MSalters doesn't look like you need the points but I would have accepted your answer since it actually tells me how to achieve my goal. Thank you!